# Auto suggestion in search with json return

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

Auto suggestion  in search with json return

I want to returning json data from database when user search in box.

And display suggestion box of searched text.

Comment: Did you have a specific programming question that we could help you with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added jquery at your tags, So, I suggest you take a look at this plugin:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

You just need to create the "availableTags" variable after process your JSON result.
To see the example, click on "view source" at link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ plugin.

It has support for having remote data source which will help you in accomplishing everything you mentioned above.

You can go through the examples given in the link for implementation details. This section http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote will be more useful for your requirement.